# Marquee tag in chrome and firefox are not working in same way

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

hello i am using marquee tag in my website which is not working in same way...

**it works in chrome** but not in firefox

```
 <marquee scrollamount="3" onmouseover=this.stop() onmouseout=this.start() direction="up">

         hello world
  </marquee>
```

**it works in firefox but not in chrome**

```
<marquee scrollamount="3" onMouseOver="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" OnMouseOut="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);" direction="up">
hello world
</marquee>
```

i want to solve this using marquee .

any suggestions?

Comment: please write a suggestion before down vote in comments...thanks

Comment: `marquee` is an archaic tag, and is no longer meant to be supported by browsers. Use CSS instead: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/xxuxd/ From MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Answer (score 2):

hello this may help by the way this is deprecated

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" onMouseOver="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);this.stop();" OnMouseOut="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 2, 0);this.start();" scrollamount="2"> hellow world </marquee>
```